# Replace char while exporting data from grid to excel

Tags: c#, export-to-excel, radgrid

I use this snippet to export the data from a radGrid:

```
protected void ExpExcel_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    foreach (GridColumn col in RadGrid1.MasterTableView.Columns)
    {
        if (col.UniqueName.Contains("notes") || (col.UniqueName.Contains("EditCommandColumn")) ||
            (col.UniqueName.Contains("column1")))
        {
            col.Display = false;
        }
        else
        {
            col.Display = true;
        }
    }
    foreach (GridFilteringItem item in RadGrid1.MasterTableView.GetItems(GridItemType.FilteringItem))
        item.Visible = false;
    RadGrid1.ExportSettings.ExportOnlyData = true;
    RadGrid1.MasterTableView.ExportToExcel();        
}
```

and it is working fine. My problem is that I need to replace one char in a column and I am a bit lost. How can I replace a specific char in a specific column when exporting to excel the data?

Answer (score 0):

If you know exactly what kind of char you want to remove, then you could use the Replace Method:

```
string a = "Example1";

a.Replace("1",string.Empty);
```

An example in your case would be:

```
col.UniqueName.Replace("[what you want to remove]", "[what you want it to replace with]");
```

Answer (score 0):

I rewrote your method and added  the replacement of any spaces (' ') with an underscore ('_') for all cells in the "notes" column:

```
protected void ExpExcel_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    foreach (GridColumn col in rgTest.MasterTableView.Columns)
    {
        col.Display = !(col.UniqueName.Contains("notes") || col.UniqueName.Contains("EditCommandColumn") || col.UniqueName.Contains("column1"));
    }

    List<Telerik.Web.UI.GridItem> items = rgTest.MasterTableView.GetItems(Telerik.Web.UI.GridItemType.FilteringItem).ToList();
    foreach (GridFilteringItem item in items)
    {
        item.Visible = false;

        // Replace any space character with an underscore:
        if (item.OwnerTableView.DataKeyNames[0] == "notes")
        {
            var c = item.Controls[0] as System.Web.UI.WebControls.TextBox;
            if (c != null)
            {
                c.Text.Replace(' ', '_');
            }
        }
    }

    rgTest.ExportSettings.ExportOnlyData = true;
    rgTest.MasterTableView.ExportToExcel();
}
```